# Getting a free(): invalid pointer error

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a program that replaces characters e  with * on a string that has the most e's,but I'm getting a random free(): invalid pointer error whenever I run this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char char1 = 'e', char2 = '*';
    int N, mostchars = 0, its;

    cout << "N = ";
    cin >> N;
    string strings[N];

    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        cin >> strings[i];
        if(mostchars < count(strings[i].begin(), strings[i].end(), char1))
        {
            mostchars = count(strings[i].begin(), strings[i].end(), char1);
            its = i;
        }
    }
    replace(strings[its].begin(), strings[its].end(), char1, char2);
    cout << strings[its] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the gdb output:

```
*** Error in `/home/hiddendirishidden/STRING/bin/Debug/STRING': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fffffffe6a0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6f364)[0x7ffff720a364]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x74d96)[0x7ffff720fd96]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7557e)[0x7ffff721057e]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9_M_mutateEmmPKcm+0xfd)[0x7ffff7b765dd]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZStrsIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEERSt13basic_istreamIT_T0_ES7_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS4_S5_T1_EE+0x314)[0x7ffff7afd624]
/home/hiddendirishidden/STRING/bin/Debug/STRING[0x400e13]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ffff71bb710]
/home/hiddendirishidden/STRING/bin/Debug/STRING[0x400c39]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1452363                            /home/hiddendirishidden/STRING/bin/Debug/STRING
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:21 1452363                            /home/hiddendirishidden/STRING/bin/Debug/STRING
00602000-00634000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff0000000-7ffff0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff0021000-7ffff4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff719b000-7ffff7333000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 396432                     /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so
7ffff7333000-7ffff7532000 ---p 00198000 08:21 396432                     /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so
7ffff7532000-7ffff7536000 r--p 00197000 08:21 396432                     /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so
7ffff7536000-7ffff7538000 rw-p 0019b000 08:21 396432                     /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so
7ffff7538000-7ffff753c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff753c000-7ffff7552000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 396763                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7552000-7ffff7751000 ---p 00016000 08:21 396763                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7751000-7ffff7752000 rw-p 00015000 08:21 396763                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7752000-7ffff7855000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 396490                     /usr/lib/libm-2.23.so
7ffff7855000-7ffff7a55000 ---p 00103000 08:21 396490                     /usr/lib/libm-2.23.so
7ffff7a55000-7ffff7a56000 r--p 00103000 08:21 396490                     /usr/lib/libm-2.23.so
7ffff7a56000-7ffff7a57000 rw-p 00104000 08:21 396490                     /usr/lib/libm-2.23.so
7ffff7a57000-7ffff7bc9000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 396798                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7ffff7bc9000-7ffff7dc9000 ---p 00172000 08:21 396798                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7ffff7dc9000-7ffff7dd3000 r--p 00172000 08:21 396798                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7ffff7dd3000-7ffff7dd5000 rw-p 0017c000 08:21 396798                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7ffff7dd5000-7ffff7dd9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7dd9000-7ffff7dfc000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 396431                     /usr/lib/ld-2.23.so
7ffff7fc5000-7ffff7fcb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff7000-7ffff7ff8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff8000-7ffff7ffa000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00023000 08:21 396431                     /usr/lib/ld-2.23.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 00024000 08:21 396431                     /usr/lib/ld-2.23.so
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff71ce2a8 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

I'm not sure why that happens. Maybe I did something wrong, after all this is the first time I'm trying out the algorithm library.

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)` did you mean `for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)` ?

Comment: @Michael Yes, thanks it works now :D

Comment: You're also potentially referencing an unassigned value.  'its' is only set if control flow enters your 'if' block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
```

You are using 1-based index. `strings` only has elements indexed from `0` to `N-1`, `strings[N]` is an invalid access.

C++ convention is 0-based indexes. Do

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
```

---

You also may like to initialize variables and check for errors on input.

Answer (score 2):

You used a variable to determine the length of an array. You cannot do this safely in C++.

Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `std::string[N]`.

Furthermore, your loop goes *1 → N*, instead of the correct *0 → N-1*. That means the `std::string` you're trying to access on the final iteration doesn't exist, and the various allocations that the `std::string` performs internally are therefore broken.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is wrong with VLA in C++? [g++ supports them as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: "Extension" being the key word. :) VLAs are not in C++.

Comment: You might be surprised, but people wrote multi-threaded applications before threads were in C++ and the sky did not fall.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Yes, by studying their compiler and diligently setting compiler flags that they know produced the correct result. OP is learning. At the very least we should educate that VLAs are not in C++. I say this primarily because I've seen cases where a compiler without VLAs (or with the extension disabled, as frankly it should be!) failed to diagnose the use of a _runtime_ constant as an array bound and all hell broke loose. I say, let's default to "don't use VLAs" when teaching. OP can always decide to keep using it, but with the new knowledge that he/she should be cautious/aware.

Comment: What was that compiler?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: GCC something or other (an old one). Don't forget that the combinations of switches you can give GCC borders on the infinite (I can't remember off the top of my head which turn off VLAs)

Comment: I would file a bug report to gcc.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: I believe I did but that specific bug is not really the point here